# Как связать чекбокс с вызовом метода?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы когда я ставлю или убираю галочку с чекбокса срабатывал метод. На метод `.click`. Но метод не реагирует на смену состояния чекбокса. Как привязать метод к чекбоксу?

```
var checkbox = ('<input type="checkbox">');

// не срабатывает но почему?
$(checkbox).click(function () {
    console.log("hello checkbox"); // ничего не выводит в консоль.
});

//печатает чекбоксы
$('#all_tasks').append(
    $('<li></li>').append(checkbox));
```

Полный код:

```
//button id.
$("#get_all_task_but").click(function(){

    // URL of servlet.
    $.ajax({
        url : 'get_all_tasks',
        type : "post",
        success : function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

                var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"/>');
                 $(checkbox).click(function () {
                     console.log("hello checkbox"); // ничего не выводит в консоль.
                });

                $('#all_tasks').append(
                    $('<li></li>').append(
                        value['id'] + "<br>").append(
                            value['desc']+ "<br>").append(
                                value['create']+ "<br>").append(
                                    checkbox + "<br>"));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

В будущем данные полученные из чекбоксов надо будет сразу отправлять на сервер ajax запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберем построчно.

```
var checkbox = ('<input type="checkbox">');
// Теперь в checkbox записана строка с html

// Создаем из этой строки html элемент
$(checkbox)
// Вешаем на него обработчик
.click(function () { 
    console.log("hello checkbox"); // ничего не выводит в консоль.
});


// Находим на странице элемент с id = all_tasks
$('#all_tasks')
// Добавляем в него
.append(
    // Созданный из строки элемент li
    $('<li></li>')
    //Добавляем еще один созданный из строки элемент (чекбокс)
     .append(checkbox)); 
     // Это не тот чекбокс, на который вы повесили обработчик.
```

```js
var checkbox = ('<input type="checkbox">');
$(document.body).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', e => { 
    console.log("hello checkbox");
});
    
$('#all_tasks').append($('<li></li>').append(checkbox));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all_tasks'></div>
```

```js
var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox">';
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT' && e.target.type==='checkbox'){
        console.log("hello checkbox");
    }
});

document.getElementById('all_tasks').innerHTML += `<li>${checkbox}</li>`
```

```html
<div id='all_tasks'></div>
```

Comment: @Regent С чего вы взяли, что он нужен только для одного?

Comment: @Regent там много чекбоксов который подгружается через ajax и потом надо что-бы эти чекбоксы реагировали. Может я не достаточно точно описал контекст проблемы.

Comment: @Pavel ага, особенно учитывая, что в вопросе у вас ровно один чекбокс и ни намёка на то, что их, на самом деле, много и что они вообще через Ajax приходят. Возможно, они и создаются вовсе не так, как вы описали в коде в вопросе (все вместе парсятся из строки, а не по отдельности)?

Comment: @Regent создаются через `.append()`

Comment: @Darth почему то при попытке скопипастить `$(document.body).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', e => { 
    console.log("hello checkbox");
});` у меня IDE подсвечивает красным и пишет Expression statement is not assignment or call

Comment: @Pavel Это из за стрелочной функции, наверное. Настройте в IDE синтаксис ES6 либо замените стрелочную функцию обычной - вместо `e =>` напишите `function(e)`

Comment: @Darth заработало только как мне определить от какого чекбокса пришел сигнал у меня их 5 в тестовом примере клик на любой приводит к тому что `console.log("hello checkbox");` срабатывает у всех а мне бы надо на сервер отправить как раз на какой из них нажали

Comment: @Pavel А чем они у вас отличаются?

Comment: @Darth отличаются id шниками. Это задачи у которой есть статус boolean done

Comment: @Pavel Ну так вы легко можете посмотреть, какой id у чекбокса - `e.target.id` в обработчике

Comment: @Darth да id посмотреть можно но получается что срабатывают обработчики во всех чекбоксах и на какой из них был сделан клик не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

В коде `$(checkbox)` парсится и создаётся один DOM-элемент из строки, а в коде `append(checkbox)` - другой.
Соответственно, раз обработчик события вы добавили первому элементу, а на страницу добавили второй, то обработчик первого элемента при клике на второй вызван не будет.

Если такой checkbox добавляется на страницу всего один, то можно создать один элемент, после чего добавить ему обработчик события и добавить его самого в `#all_tasks`:

```js
var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"/>');
$checkbox.on("click", function() {
  console.log("hello checkbox");
});
$('#all_tasks').append($('<li></li>').append($checkbox));
```

```html
<ul id="all_tasks"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если checkbox-ов создаётся много, то имеет смысл воспользоваться делегированием события, добавив checkbox-ам для их опознавания, например, класс:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".hello", function() {
  console.log("hello checkbox");
});
var $allTasks = $('#all_tasks');
var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' class='hello'/>";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  $allTasks.append($('<li></li>').append(checkbox));
}
```

```html
<ul id="all_tasks"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: я добавил полный код извините что голову вам заморочил хотел покороче чтобы читалось легче а получилось "как всегда..."

Comment: @Pavel я вариант обработки множества checkbox-ов добавил в конец ответа. Если его адаптировать для вашего кода, то должно работать без проблем.